# Getting a While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) 503 error when attempting to install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

This is the error I get when I try to do a "gem install rails -v 4.1.0" using Ruby 2.1.1 and RVM.

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) bad
>   response Service Unavailable 503
>   (http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord)

Not sure what is causing this, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: show me your gem file please

Comment: @JitenK There is no Gemfile as Rails is not installing. The gem list for the current RVM gemset is as follows. bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.6.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)

Answer (score 4):

It would be a ssl problem.

Change your gem sources and try again.

```
gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your rvm ssl certificates are up to date.

Check their status

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

Update them!

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Also try

```
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

Comment: I saw the ssl cert commands on a google search. Unfortunately both do nothing :/. My OpenSSL is updated to 1.0.1g and the rvm ssl cert commands all return that my certificates are as up to date as possible. Running the gem install rails command with the --include-dependencies yields the same results as before. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just a server problem.

I waited a few minutes and tried again and it worked.