# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError with gems.github.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I got an error with:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I tried to install the bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

The error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (http://gems.github.com/quick/Marshal.4.8/bundler-0.3.0.gemspec.rz)
```

I solved momentarily with this command:

```
 gem sources --remove "http://gems.github.com"
```

Because it is 403 Forbidden problem.
Idea from: [Getting a While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) 503 error when attempting to install rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351405/getting-a-while-executing-gem-gemremotefetcherfetcherror-503-error-whe)

Any ideas how to solve or why this error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your gem sources and try again:

```
gem sources --remove http://gems.github.com/
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the rubygems page is blocked from the main serve, specifically https conection. change to https in Gemfile or ask them to unblock the ruby.org and api.ruby.org page.